# Why this program doesn't give output?

Tags: c++, file-io, multidimensional-array

Just two days ago i apparently found the solution to make my program run and works correctly. I say apparently because today i'm trying to use it but it doesn't work anymore. I don't make any change to the code, so i don't understand for which reason in doesn't execute anymore. 
Teorically this program should open a .dat file, read and parse it extracting only the column that i need, in this case the second. Once exctract the column, it would calculate the mean of the data by set of 120 elements using an array.
Two days ago it worked correctly, today it doesn't give any output and the debugging functions doesn't show any errors.
The code is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

#define FATAL(MSG) do { \
    std::cerr << "Errore: " << MSG << '\n'; \
    exit(1); \
} while (false)

int main()
{
   std::ifstream fin ("P01-05 tensione di vapore di riferimento fino                        180°C.dat");
   if (fin.is_open())
   {
       std::ofstream fout("tmean.dat");
       if (fout.is_open())
       {
          fout << "Tmean\n";
          std::string line;
          while (getline(fin, line))
         {
            const int group_size = 120;
            double temp[group_size];
            double total = 0;
            for (int i=0; i < group_size; ++i)
            {
                if (getline(fin, line))
                {
                    std::istringstream ss(line);
                    double time;
                    if (ss >> time >> temp[i])
                        total += temp[i];
                    else
                        FATAL("unable to parse 2 doubles from line '"
                              << line << "' for [" << i << ']');
                }
                else
                    // will rarely happen after checking !eof()
                    FATAL("failed to read needed line from file for ["
                          << i << ']');
            }
            double tmean = total / group_size;
            fout << tmean << '\n';       
        }
    }
    else
        FATAL("could not open output file.");
        fout.close(); 
}
else
    FATAL("non si puo aprire il file.");
    fin.close();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Compile your program with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)....) then **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`) to run your program step by step, etc.

Comment: Does the filename really have such a large amount of white space in it?  If it has, is it still reachable from your 'current directory', (since you do not use an absolute path).

Comment: This file-name seems suspect: `"P01-05 tensione di vapore di riferimento fino                        180°C.dat"` -- all the whitespace won't paste into this comment.  And it has to be in the same directory as the executable.

Comment: As a rulf of thumb, use shorter file names (perhaps organized in subdirectories) and avoid spaces in file names.

Comment: Also, your issue might be operating system and file system specific. On Linux, you could also use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand which syscalls failed

Comment: _"I don't make any change to the code, so i don't understand for which reason in doesn't execute anymore."_ You are mistaken. You changed _something_.

Comment: @Paolo Orsatti: Ehm, you should choose you file names more... carefully.

Comment: @Paul Evans the problem or error is not about the file's name, because i tried to open it with a program that simply read from a file and it works. And the file is already in the directory of the executable.

Answer (score 0):

Your program compiled and worked for me.   The absence of fatal stdio messages coming from your code might mean everything is working.  I was able to cause all FATAL messages to execute.  Confirm that dioporco.dat isn't being written somewhere else on your file system.   What may be happening is that when you run the program the "current directory" isn't what you think it is and the program is being run somewhere else and thus dioporco.dat is being written "there".   You might also try changing dioporco.dat to a fully qualified name like "/home/myuser/dioporco.dat".   As the open is written now, that file will be created wherever the OS believes the current directory is set when the program executes.   Search your file system for dioporco.dat and you may find its being created successfully.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I've applied your sugguestion but it doesn't give any output again! I'm really upset